# Complexity of polynomial simplification into standard form

Tags: polynomials, optimization, computational-complexity

I am curious to know if any given $n$-variable polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[\mathbf{x}]$, not in standard form, can be simplified by an algorithm in polynomial time. The polynomial is
$$ p(\mathbf{x}) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{m}p_i(\mathbf{x})^{k_i}.$$ The entries of the problem are:

$n \rightarrow \text{number of variables};$

$d_i \rightarrow \text{degree of each polynomial $p_i(\mathbf{x})$}$;

$ p_i(\mathbf{x}) \rightarrow \text{random polynomials of degree $d_i$};$

$m \rightarrow \text{number of random polynomials}$;

$k_i \rightarrow \text{positive integer}.$

For better understanding, let the polynomial

$$\small p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1 + x_2x_3)^3 + (x_2+x_3 +3)^2 + (x_1-x_2 +1).$$ It can be simplified in its standard form as

$$\small p(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_2^3x_3^3 + 3x_1x_2^2x_3^2+3x_1^2x_2x_3 + x_1^3 +x_3^2 +x_2^2 +2x_2x_3+6x_3 +6x_2+x_1 -x_2+10.$$

If this problem cannot be solved in polynomial time, what is its complexity class?

**Remark:** In the standard form of an $n$-variable polynomial $p(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{\mathbf{\alpha}}{p_{\mathbf{\alpha}}x^{\mathbf{\alpha}}}$, with $\mathbf{\alpha} \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$, all monomials $x^{\mathbf{\alpha}}$ are unique.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Polynomial time relative to what? Sum of the lengths of the input and output expressions? (Either the input or the output can be made much longer than the other.)

Comment: What kind of expressions appear in the input? Only composition of polynomials, or do you input also any elementary function, or more? Notice that for elementary functions you can always compute all derivatives at the origin and that gives you the polynomial. Computing **one** derivative is polynomial time with respect to the number of operations defining the expression.

Comment: Now, for elementary functions in general one would need to bound the number of derivatives to be computed. I am not sure if this is even decidable. For the case of composition of polynomials the degree is easy (poly time in terms of the number of operations and number of variables in the input) to bound and therefore the number of derivatives to be computed.

Comment: @DavidK, I have edited the problem. I hope this clear now.

Comment: @Pp.., I didn't understand why did you talk about derivatives.

Comment: @AlexSilva It is a way to imagine the computation of the coefficients in the expansion. Remember Taylor series? Let me write it down.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that for every polynomial $p(x)$

$$p(x)=\sum \frac{f^{(\alpha)}(0)}{\alpha!}x^\alpha$$

Here $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)$, $f^{(\alpha)}=\frac{\partial^{\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}...\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}f$, $x^{\alpha}=x_1^{\alpha_1}...x_n^{\alpha_n}$, and $\alpha!=\alpha_1!...\alpha_n!$.

So, as long as you can compute the $f^{(\alpha)}(0)$ in polynomial time we are done.

But how do we (/can we) compute derivatives of a polynomial expression as the one you wrote?

Comment: I don't know if you have read the question completely, but I am talking about multivariate polynomials.

Comment: @AlexSilva Taylor is true for any number of variables.

Comment: But, what is $\alpha !$ since $\alpha$ is a vector? Your Taylor representation is very simplified and doesn't give any important information.

Comment: @AlexSilva Let me add the common notation above.